# modal popup closed automatically when parent modified via signalr

Tags: signalr, simplemodal

I have a problem where the modal popup is closed when signalr updates the parent web page. Is there any way to update the parent web page without closing the popup? Or even to not proceed with the update if a modal popup is open?

In my software signalr updates messages on the web page every minute, so when a modal popup is opened, it will be closed automatically in less than a minute.

I guess one solution would be in the client hub methods that display the messsages, I could try to detect if there are any open modal popups and not proceed with the update if any are found. How could I do that?

Comment: Don't worry about this. It was a bug in my code. I closed the modal popup in some other javascript